# How to find out only one record in database using stored procedure by database.Sqlquery()

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I intend to create this example to present my problem.

I have a table in my database:

[image]

I then created a stored procedure to find a record by Id

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get 
    @id INT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM a 
    WHERE id = @id
END
```

Next, I use `Database.SqlQuery()` to execute this stored procedure:

```
a record = db.Database.SqlQuery<a>("sp_get @id", new SqlParameter("@id",id));
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery[test_sp_insert_edit_remove.Database.a] to 'test_sp_insert_edit_remove.Database.a'

Yes I know it is wrong but I have no idea to solve this error.

Help me fix that error

Comment: what is the issue are you facing/?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `"I have no idea to solve this error. Help me fix that error"` ← What error? You did not include any error information. Is it a compile time error? If so include the full error message and what line it occurs on. Is it an Exception you get at runtime? If so include the entire exception including the message, stack trace, type, and repeat for nested exceptions. [edit] your question and include those details.

Comment: My purpose is get a record by execute SP_GET and then assign it to record variable that type of a @viveknuna

Comment: Change `a record` to `var record`. Now hover over `var`. What does it show?

Answer (score 0):

I will help you by giving example. so that you canrefer the concept and apply in your program. Lets say you need to get the student name. so you will run query like this.

```
string studentName = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select studentName from Student where studentid=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", 1))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

So in your case you have to create a class equivalent to the table and use it. lets say `<ClassName>`

Comment: yes I  know but is there any way to solve that problem by stored procedure?

Comment: yes it is fine but I want to solve this error by stored procedure? Can you help me to to that.